# Find Each Occurrence of X and Insert a Carriage Return

Tags: vb.net

A colleague has some data he is putting into a flat file (.txt) and needs to insert a carriage return before EACH occurrence of 'POL01', 'SUB01','VEH01','MCO01'.

I did use:

```
For Each line1 As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(BodyFileLoc)
            If line1.Contains("POL01") Or line1.Contains("SUB01") Or line1.Contains("VEH01") Or line1.Contains("MCO01") Then
                Writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine & line1)
            Else
                Writer.WriteLine(line1)
            End If
        Next
```

But unfortunately it turns out that the file is not formatted in 'lines' by SSIS but as one whole string.

How can I insert a carriage return before every occurrence of the above?

**Test Text**

```
POL01CALT302276F              332                 NBPM          00101                 20151113201511130001201611132359                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      2015111300010020151113000100SUB01CALT302276F              332                 NBPMP01            Akl            Abi-Khalil                                            19670131   M                                                                                                                             U33 Stoford Close                                                                                    SW19 6TJ                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            2015111300010020151113000100VEH01CALT302276F              332                 NBPM001LV56 LEJ                        N 2006VAUXHALL                                                                            CA                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       2015111300010020151113000100MCO01CALT302276F              332                 NBPM0101 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                2015111300010020151113000100POL01CALT742569N
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions for this, specifically by using [`Regex.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z(v=vs.110).aspx) to find and replace each occurrence of the strings you're looking for with a newline followed by the matching text:

```
Dim str as String = "xxxPOL01xxxSUB01xxxVEH01xxxMCO01xxx"
Dim output as String = Regex.Replace(str, "((?:POL|SUB|VEH|MCO)01)", Environment.NewLine + "$1")

'output contains:   
'xxx
'POL01xxx
'SUB01xxx
'VEH01xxx
'MCO01xxx
```

There may be a better way to construct this regular expression, but this is a simple alternation on the different letters, followed by `01`.  This matched text is represented by the `$1` in the replacement string.

If you're new to regular expressions, there are a number of tools that help you understand them - for example, [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/tH4vB9/2) will show you an explanation of the one I have used here:

[image]

Comment: James what about if the SUB01 etc aren't at the start of the string, please see above some test text I have got.

Comment: It shouldn't matter - it will still find them and put each on a new line.  Running your updated example through works in my test code here?

Comment: Hi James, using the above it only highlights the first occurrence of POL01 for me on regex101.com

Comment: You'll need to show more code - [it works fine](http://imgur.com/ypNgrZ2) for me.  Ah - that's on regex101, note that on my original link I didn't set any of the flags that would be needed for successful testing in that environment, you'll need to put `g` in the flags box to make it a global search.  With `Regex.Replace` in .NET you won't need it.

Comment: [Here's an updated regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tH4vB9/2) with the global flag set.  I'll update the link in the answer too.  Note that I just meant for this site to be supplemental as an explanation of the regex, not for it to actually do the replacements.